# How Do I Detect the Adobe Acrobat Version Installed in Firefox via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox, plugins, version, acrobat

I know this can be done in IE by creating an ActiveX object, but how do I do it in FF. The navigator.plugins['Adobe Acrobat'] object lets me know if it's installed or not, but it doesn't contain the version number. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

`navigator.plugins[n].name` where `n` is the index of the Acrobat plugin is supposed have the version number in it. Unfortunately, starting with Adobe Reader 8, they changed the name to `"Adobe PDF Plug-In for Firefox and Netscape"`, with no version information. So, if this is the name you've detected at least Reader 8, but can't tell versions 8 from 9.

Also, make sure you take into account that Macs don't need Acrobat Reader to render PDF files. (I booted my Windows partition just to test this.)

Comment: Great answer. Is this available on IE as well or is a different method needed?

Comment: Good advice about the Macs, but this solution has the same problem as the SWFObject one, the description for Adobe Acrobat doesn't include a version number.

Comment: Regarding the IE comment, this description method can be used for other plugins on IE, but a more reliable way is to create an ActiveXObject as described here: http://www.builtfromsource.com/tag/safari/

Comment: Sorry Snocrash - I didn't realize that Adobe stopped putting version numbers in there with v8. I updated the answer with more info.

Comment: No system needs Acrobat Reader to render PDF files. I'm much happier with Foxit on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/AdobeReaderDetect.htm

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to do this like swfobject detects flash version:

[SWFObject source code](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/source/browse/tags/swfobject_2_1/src/swfobject.js)

Comment: I would have said it if you hadn't - SWFObject is making the lives of thousands of web developers easier, one include at a time.

Comment: Good advice, I hadn't thought to look there, but unfortunately it only works because the navigator.plugins['Shockwave Flash'].description actually contains the version number. Adobe Acrobat doesn't do this, the only thing in their description is "Adobe PDF Plug-In for Firefox and Netscape".

Answer (score 0):

```
var p = document.getElementById('Pdf1');
//p.GetVersions()
if(p.GetVersions().indexOf("7.0") != -1)
    alert("Acrobat 7 Found")
```

Comment: What is the element with ID 'Pdf1' supposed to be? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

This script detects the reader in all browsers - even detects Chrome's PDF Reader...

[Acrobat Detection Javascript code](http://thecodeabode.blogspot.com/2011/01/detect-adobe-reader-plugin.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
var browser_info = {
    name: null,
    acrobat : null,
    acrobat_ver : null
  };


if(navigator.plugins != null)
  {      
   var acrobat = navigator.plugins['Adobe Acrobat'];
   if(acrobat == null)
   {           
    browser_info.acrobat = null;
    return browser_info;
   }
   browser_info.acrobat = "installed";
   browser_info.acrobat_ver = parseInt(acrobat.version[0]);                   
  }


where navigator is the property of Window
```